Want to display amount format to Indian 3,60,000 in php
I want to display the amount format to be displayed in Indian Currency format has 3,60,000.00 Instead of 3,600,000. How can I change the format in php
<?php
$number = 1000000;
$formatted_number = '₹' . number_format($number, 0, '.', ',');
echo $formatted_number;
?>

The above code displays amount has 1,000,000

install php intl extension and use
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_IN', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$formatted_number = $formatter->formatCurrency($number, 'INR');

This will give the output you desire ₹3,60,000 with the currency symbol if you require just the separators like of number_format then use
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_IN', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$formatted_number = $formatter->format($number);

intl (Internationalization Functions) is made for this type of internalization tasks.
